# Remove unwanted websites or apps from the Notifications list

Tags: macos, mac, notifications

Some websites send "spam" notifications to my Mac.

I can turn these notifications:

> 1. On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Settings, then click Notifications  in the sidebar. (You may need to scroll down.)
> 2. Below Application Notifications on the right, click an app or website, then turn off “Allow notifications.”
>
> You won’t receive notifications for it until you turn on “Allow notifications” again.

But how to *remove* these websites from this list?

[image]